# Is it possible to send mail in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, smtp

Is there any way to send mail in oracle ? Can anyone give an example.

I tried but not working.

Comment: Put here your code and then ask why it's not working

Comment: In addition to code, tell us what "not working" means to you.  If you're getting an error, include that error.

Comment: I tried send procedure of utl_mail package i.e utl_mail.send using proper parameters. I' got what was wrong. my smtp host and port were empty when later I checked (from v$instance table). After updating correct host and port, code worked fine. thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  I've sent mail via Oracle before by using UTL_SMTP (though, I think the "newer" way to do it these days is with UTL_MAIL).

Here is a link which will describe how to do this.  Has examples too.

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Send_mail_from_PL/SQL